# nm: File format not recognized

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, g++

I am trying to link a library test.a into an executable using the GCC toolchain.

I have never experienced something similar when using CMake, everything seems to run smoothly until

```
> [100%] Linking CXX executable test
ar qc lib/test.a  CMakeFiles/test.dir/keys.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test.dir/test2.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/test.dir/test3.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/test.dir/test4.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/test.dir/test5.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/test.dir/test6.cpp.o
```

Where the linker complains

```
> test.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

test.a contains the following object files:

```
> ar -t test.a
test1.cpp.o
test2.cpp.o
test3.cpp.o
test4.cpp.o
test5.cpp.o
test6.cpp.o
```

nm does not recognize the format of the files:

```
nm -s test.a
nm: test1.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: test2.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: test3.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: test4.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: test5.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: test6.cpp.o: File format not recognized
```

Even though the file says these are ASCII files:

```
file test1.cpp.o
test1.cpp.o: ASCII text
```

I am stuck.

How do I figure out where the problem lies?

Comment: Why are the .o's ASCII files? For example, running file on a .o on my machine gives me `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

Comment: @Kevin thanks, your comment was the right pointer to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even though file says these are ascii files

That is your problem right there: the `.o` files are supposed to be (compiled) *object* files in whatever native format your system uses, and *not* ASCII files.

You most likely screwed up your `Makefile` (or `CMakefile`). But you didn't show them, so no further help can be given.

P.S. It is also highly unusual to name files `test1.cpp.o` -- usually `test1.cpp` is compiled into `test1.o`.

Comment: About the P.S.: it's not "highly unusual"; it's what CMake generates for the object file names. It has less collision possibility (`test1.cpp` and `test1.c`, when compiled, there's no collision if you just append `.o` to the filename).

Answer (score 2):

I had the option -MM as a compile flag which resulted in dependency lists beeing built instead of object files.